# Ajax not working in synchronous manner

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am using `prototype.js` for making Ajax  request. Everything was working fine till I changed `asynchronous` to `false` (As I want to make synchronous requests). Following are the few lines from my code.

```
    var commOptions = {
                contentType: 'text/xml',
                method: 'post',
                asynchronous: true,
                evalJS: false,
                evalJSON: false
            };   
   sProxy_Url = sUrl;  
   new Ajax.Request(sProxy_Url, commOptions);
```

If I change `asynchronous` to `false` then Ajax do not work. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: define not working because it works here http://jsfiddle.net/HRu78/

Comment: @Esailija: I Ajax call gives HTML response. If I change `asynchronous` to `false` I didnt see any response.

Comment: Add the code where you are supposed to handle the response to your question because the jsfiddle is working fine with the code you gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I don't see what's not working, I even got the response in javascript to make sure:

```
var commOptions = {
                contentType: 'text/xml',
                method: 'post',
                asynchronous: false,
                evalJS: false,
                evalJSON: false
            };   

   var a = new Ajax.Request("/", commOptions);
console.log( a.transport.responseText.length ); //16898
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HRu78/1/

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'm not telling you how to design your app but in my experience whenever I've thought I definitely needed to use synchronous, it's always turned out that there's an asynchronous way of doing things that's better.

Comment: I will try to get it done in asynchronous way. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's just about always recommended to make ajax requests asynchronous since making them synchronous will block the main JavaScript thread, which provides a poor user experience (see [this](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options)).

However, if you really want to use the synchronous option you'll need to be a bit more clear about what's happening when you run the code - does the browser block? Or does the function return but with no data?

Comment: I HAVE to use it synchronously. When I make synchronous call I get response with no data.

Comment: By "you'll need to be a bit more clear" I think tinyd meant he'd need to know what property you read, what the HTTP status code returned was, probably even paste all the relevant code.  How long does it take to not work - is it instantaneous?

Comment: @thomasrutter - yes, that's what I meant alright! Ajinkya - It would be worth looking in Firebug (or Chrome, or IE) logs to see if the request is being sent. Also, can you say which browsers you're seeing the error in?